# Showing items under multiple selected categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-multiselect

I have list of categories like below.

```
<select name="category[]" id="category"  multiple="multiple">     
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Cate_1</option>
                <option value="2">Cate_2</option>
                <option value="3">Cate_3</option>
                <option value="4">Cate_4</option>
                <option value="5">Cate_5</option>
                <option value="6">Others</option>
</select>
```

User can select multiple categories, I am using [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin for that.

Below this I want to only the items that is from these categories.
These items or also multiple selectable.

The I am having is *whenever the dropdown list opens it pushes the content down*.
Also,
**How can I load the items under selected categories?**

I tried making a ajax get call when there is change in selecting category.

```
$('#category').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '165px',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                        var categories= $('#category option:selected');
                        var selected = [];
                        $(categories).each(function(index, category){
                           selected.push([$(this).val()]);
                           });
                       $.post("get-items-under-selected-categories",
                         {
                           category: selected
                         },
                        function(data, status){
                           alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                        });

        });
```

Comment: I see some question marks regarding your code, first off, should `favorite.push` not be `category.push`? Second, with the line `$("input[name='category']:checked")` are you trying to refer to `select name="category[]"` ? or haven't you shown us all the html?

Comment: I fixed favourite. Yes , `select name="category[]` this one.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I fixed it, now I can get selected categories. Please tell me how can I load the listed under each category and display. Should I use ajax post? Or should I load all the items and do some hide and show? please help.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send the ajax call to retrieve the selected category related information.

i can see two issues in you javascript code.

1. } closing bracket missing in multiselect.
2. you need to push the actual value to selected array instead of selected.push([$(this).val()]);.

update javascript will look like below.

```
$(function () {

    $('#category').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '165px',
        onChange: function (option, checked, select) {
            var categories = $('#category option:selected');
            var selected = [];
            $(categories).each(function (index, category) {
                selected.push($(this).val());
            });
            debugger;
            $.post("get-items-under-selected-categories", {
                    category: selected
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

if your posting the information to php. you can use the below code retrieve the posted selected category.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($_POST['category'] as $code => $name) 
    {
        echo  $name.'<br />';

    }
?>
```